# Artifacts when drawing Qt & Java apps after durable work on Ubuntu 15.10 (and other)

Tags: java, qt, unix, xorg

Short history of problem:

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 I had some problems with any Qt-apps after durable work with IntellijIDEA. In apps like tortoisehg I saw painting problems, like not filled areas or shifted text. It was fixed after reading post in [archlinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200167). Just set up property for Qt and changed my openjdk to oracle's.

The next story, that possibly is relative to first, consists in my work in IntellijIDEA and other Java swing applications (like Netbeans RCP): after long term working some dialogs became transparent, were inaccessible or just clicked through it to something under. Reopen of the dialog or window helps, but my colleagues have same problems on other OS, like Fedora (with KDE).

This bug is annoying, because our product is written on Netbeans and works under *nix distributive. Sometimes we stuck with problem of click-through problem: dialog or window just clicked into window after it.

I think the problem in wrong settings of x-server and in Qt- and Java- toolkit clash. This leads to artifacts on both application groups.

Does anybody stuck with this problem and do you have some ideas to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is described in Russian here (https://toster.ru/q/267833?e=3090918#clarification_329784).

Some bugs of it are found in:

1. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=350976
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1512760

Summary: the Java and Qt applications use shmem that is never cleaned by Java, after some time Qt cannot use this memory to work right. Google it with words «Java Qt shmem».